# How to use code function for Root parameter in Registry section entry?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to set a registry key to `HKLM` when user is an administrator or `HKCU` when user is a normal user.

I tried this:

```
[Registry]
Root: "{code:DefRegRoot}"; Subkey: "Software\MyCompany\MySW\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "InstallPath"; ValueData: "{app}"

[Code]
function IsRegularUser(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not (IsAdminLoggedOn or IsPowerUserLoggedOn);
end;

function DefRegRoot(Param: String): String;
begin
  if IsRegularUser then
    Result := HKCU
  else
    Result := HKLM;
end;
```

But the compiler returns an error on the first Registry line:

```
Parameter "Root" is not a valid value.
```

Any suggestion about this ?

Comment: Given that `PrivilegesRequired` is fixed at compile time, there is no point trying to make a single installer do both per-machine and per-user installs.  Pick one yourself and run with it.

Comment: What is your `PrivilegesRequired` directive set to? By default your setup will never have run as a non admin user, and if a non admin user tries to run it, then your settings will be saved for the user they elevate to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use function as a [`Root`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_registrysection.htm#Root) parameter value getter. I'd workaround this situation by using [`Check`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm#Check) condition like this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\MyCompany\MySW\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "InstallPath"; ValueData: "{app}"; Check: IsRegularUser 
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\MyCompany\MySW\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "InstallPath"; ValueData: "{app}"; Check: not IsRegularUser

[Code]
function IsRegularUser: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not (IsAdminLoggedOn or IsPowerUserLoggedOn);
end;
```